# gcloud compute vpn-tunnels describe [NAME] doesn't all details of a vpn-tunnel

Tags: google-compute-engine, vpn, gcloud

Once you have a vpn tunnel up and running there does not appear to be a method to view all the details of the tunnel from either the Google Cloud Console or the gcloud command line. Specifically the route policies that were configured when the tunnel was initially setup are missing from the describe.

Is there a method to see this information?

Answer (score 1):

This a [known behavior](https://issuetracker.google.com/71566929). The Developers Console doesn't set the remoteTrafficSelector when creating the tunnels through it.
The Developers Console creates the necessary routes and shows the "Remote ranges" based on them.
The workaround is to create the VPN tunnels using the [Compute API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/vpnTunnels/insert) or [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/) with the following [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/vpn-tunnels/create):

```
gcloud compute vpn-tunnels create NAME --region=REGION --peer-address=PEER_ADDRESS --shared-secret=SHARED_SECRET --target-vpn-gateway=TARGET_VPN_GATEWAY --local-traffic-selector=CIDR --remote-traffic-selector=CIDR
```

You can click on the star icon in the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/71566929) to get updates when there is any progress on it.

Note: This doesn't have any impact on the VPN tunnel functionality.